# preg_replace entire words

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little tag cloud that shows the last 20 searches and I am trying to make it so it will never show any keywords that start with the number 0 or 1. I have a problem with google searching for random crap starting with 0 and 1. Google is inputing crap like 
0 1 1 0 0â€°9 1ï¿½Ã¨7 0â€¡0ï¿½Â§7
into my form and it makes my tag cloud look like crap so I would like it to not show.

Here is basically what I am using to display tags right now.

> $num = '1';
>               $result=mysql_query("select keyword, time from keywords order by time DESC LIMIT 20");
>                  while (($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) && ($num <= '20')) {
>                   $word = $row[0];
>                   $time = $row[1];
>   echo "".$word."";
>   $num++;
>   }

$word is what I need to filter and display. I have tried to figure out a way with preg_replace but can only get it to remove the first number.

Does anyone know how I can remove all words starting with 0 or 1 in $word? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip them from the database select

```
select keyword, time from keywords WHERE keyword REGEXP '^[:alpha:]' ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 20
```

This will get from the database only keywords that start with a alpha char

If you don't want to use the select, you can do it in php with something like:

```
$result=mysql_query("select keyword, time from keywords order by time DESC LIMIT 20");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if (preg_match('^\w',$row[0])) {
        $word = $row[0];
        $time = $row[1];
        echo "".$word."";
    }
}
```

This will echo only the words that start with a alpha char.

Comment: the sql query seems to work great. I had to remove order before WHERE in your sql. I think that is a typo of yours. Other than that, works excellent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not, totally sure what ur asking.  But you could do,

```
if(substr($word, 0, 1) === 0 || substr($word, 0, 1) === 1) {
    $word = '';
    }
```

That way if the first character of $word is 0 or 1 it will return NULL.